# run animation on button in xcode spriteKit Game

Tags: ios, xcode, button, sprite-kit

I want to add an animation to button in sprite Kit, such as the play button found in Candy Crush Saga.

Link for Candy Crush Saga: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KAMUWIqYN24

Do I use an image sequence? Or do I scale the size of the button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's better to use SKAction to scale the button by using those methods assuming your button is a SKSpriteNode

```
 + scaleXTo:y:duration:
 + scaleYTo:duration:
```

for example

```
SKAction * yScale=[SKAction scaleYTo:0.4 duration:.5]
SKAction * xScale=[SKAction scaleXTo:0.5 duration:.5]
```

and you repeat the action for ever

```
[buttonSprite runAction:[SKAction repeatActionForever:[SKAction sequence:@[xScale, yScale]]]];
```

EDIT: you need to give a name to your SKSpriteNode button like this

```
buttonSprite = @"NAME";//to identify the button in touchesBegan
```

And the implement

```
- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {

    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInNode:self];
    SKNode *node = [self nodeAtPoint:location];

    if ([node.name isEqualToString:@"NAME"]) {
        //DO SOMETHING 

    }
}
```

Comment: do you mean create a spriteNode for the button? But how can you add the event to click the button then?

Comment: I add an explanation in my answer .